# Inner Div overflow issue?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have two containers which are both children of a `main-content` div. Whenever the second container (or any for that matter) overflow i can scroll over, BUT both the divs overflow, just the content.

For instance, the image below shows the second container overflowing, but the background colors do not expand the entire way as i scroll. Iv'e tried absolute positioning, but the results are not what i need.

Also, I would like any padding to be included when scrolling. For example, is i set my padding to be `padding: 0 10px` i want to be able to scroll 10px more than the overflowing content (considering my div will expand?)

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4mpue0gw/) of the replicated issue.

[image]

UPDATE:

I can fix the issue by setting each individual div's background color and also setting the main background color, but that seems a bit unclean and I would rather have a better way to get the desired results.

This [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4mpue0gw/1/) is my desired result, but there are so many "hacks" like setting `font-size` to `0`, setting the `main-content`'s background color, setting each div's background color, etc. I am trying to get the same result without all these workarounds.

Comment: Do you expect the divs to expand to the width of the text or to wrap the text?

Comment: @EricMartinez Please look at my updated question. I added a JSFIDDLE of the desired result and all the `workarounds` I used to get it. I am trying to get a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to use table layout.

```
.main-container {
   display: table;
}
.container, .second-container{
   display: table-row;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/4mpue0gw/2/

Comment: Good answer this works, but i cannnot add padding to the container and second container. Is there anyway I would be able to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Also, for some reason my entire page is scrolling, not just the inner div?

Comment: instead of `table-row` for the inner containers, added `overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 30px;`. [http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/4mpue0gw/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/4mpue0gw/4/)

Comment: Also added another wrap for the overflow

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `display: table` to `.main-container` class.

```
.main-container{
    display: table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mpue0gw/3/)**

```
.main-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    color: #AAA;
    background: #343434;
}
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.second-container {
    height: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #454545;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this CSS:-**

```
.main-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    color: #AAA;
    display: table;
}
.container {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background: #343434;
    display: table-row;
}
.container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.second-container {
    min-height: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #454545;
    display: table-row;
    padding: 10px;
}
.second-container > div {
    display: table-row;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```